# Compute a limit based on two sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $0<x<y\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider two sequences, $\{a_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ defined by the following recurrences. $$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{a_{n-1}}} {\sqrt{2a_{n-1}+1}}\;\;a_0=\gamma>0 $$ $$y_n=a_{n-1}(x+y_{n-1})\;\;y_0=y$$
Now I want to evaluate the following limit. $$Limit_{n\rightarrow \infty}\;\frac{y_n-x}{\frac{1}{2}^n}$$ I know that $a_n$ converges to $1/2$ and so obviously $y_n$ converges to $x$. But beyond this, I do not know how to evaluate this limit. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to evaluate the limit or just show that it exists? The last is doable, the first probably need some smart trick.

Comment: Yes because I would like to know how its value depends on $(y-x)$ and $\gamma$

Comment: I think there is little hope to get explicit formulae. But perhaps it is of interest to you just to be able to calculate the limit on a computer? That is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much hope for an explicit formula for the limit. But just to see that the limit exists or to be able to calculate it on a computer is not quite obvious, either. Setting
$ \Delta_n = a_n -\frac{1}{2}$
the iteration $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{\frac{a_{n}}{2a_{n}+1}}$ becomes:
$$ \Delta_{n+1} = \frac{\Delta_{n}}{4} \frac{2}{1+\Delta_n+\sqrt{(1+\Delta_n)(1+2\Delta_n)}}$$
With initially: $\Delta_0=\gamma-1/2>-1/2$. It is not difficult to see that $\Delta_n$ goes to zero and then that it behaves for $n$ large like $$\Delta_n \sim \frac{C}{4^n}.$$
For $y_n$ we have 
$$y_{n+1}-x= (\frac12 + \Delta_{n}) (y_n-x) + 2\Delta_n x.$$ 
Introducing $z_n = 2^n (y_n-x)$, $z_0=y-x$ we obtain 
$$ z_{n+1} = (1+2\Delta_{n})\  z_{n} + 2^{n+2}\Delta_n x$$
using that $\Delta_n\sim C 4^{-n}$ we have asymptotically:
$$ z_{n+1} = (1+ C 4^{-n})\; z_n + 2^{-n} \times 4 Cx $$
which is (fairly easily) seen to be convergent. The requested limit is $\lim_n z_n$. The above may be  implemented on a computer.